# how string.slice(0, -1) works for a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I know that in string with name example `example.slice(0, -1)` it removes last character from it.

How does it do that? How `slice(0, -1)` removes last character from a string?

Comment: Are you asking about how it is implemented, or why does it work like that?

Comment: how it works like that

Comment: this has enough explanation here [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Comment: thanks, that is what I wanted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it is by the definition.

> A negative index can be used, indicating an offset from the end of the sequence.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

It works like `length` of the string is given to second parameter.

```js
const s = 'abcdefg'
console.log(s.slice(0, -1 + s.length))
// abcdef
console.log(s.slice(0, -1))
// abcdef
```